# Get the camera normal in GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have an OpenGL scene where I look at an object like this:

```
gluLookAt(10, 10, -10, -10, -10, 10, 0, 1, 0);
```

so I know if I want to use the z-axis of my camera in the shaders it will look like a normalized vector of this one:

```
vec3(1.0, 1.0, -1,0);
```

Is there a way to compute this vector **in the vertex shader**?

I thought of computing the normal of the near/far clipping plane, but can't find a way to do this in the vertex (or fragment) shader.

I'm using the old pipeline (OpenGL v2.0/ GLSL v. 1.10) and don't want to pass the vector to the shader (although I know this would be the usual and performant way to do this).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add OpenGL version (and GLSL version, if relevant) to OpenGL/GLSL questions. `gluLookAt` is deprecated, but it's still used as a phrase in discussiosn about OpenGL, thus I don't know whether you use it technically here or just for illustration.

Comment: There was no GLSL for OpenGL 1.1.; that started with OpenGL 2.0

Comment: Sorry, it's OpenGL v2.0 / GLSL v1.10

Comment: That makes more sense now. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed function vertex transform worked by applying two matrices:

1. the "ModelView" matrix transforming from object space to eye space
2. the "Projection" matrix transforming from eye space to clip space

What `gluLookAt()` does is specifying the view matrix, by defining some camera in *world space*. And what you seem to want to reconstruct is the viewing direction in this world space.

However, this is *not possible* with fixed function GL. All you have got is the *product* `view * model`. You can't decompose it into the `view` and `model` parts without further information. And none of this information is present in fixed function GL - it never ever *had* a world space, or cared about a separate view matrix. That distinction did happen - if at all - in the application logic.

The interesting question is: what do you even need the world space's viewing direction for? Fixed function GL does such calculations in eye space, where the viewing direction is simply (0,0,-1,0).

So I see two options for you:

1. use an uniform (or other means of transfering data to the shader) to specify some additional information, like the other answers already have suggested
2. do your calculations directly in eye space

Comment: Point 2. made it. I wanted to compute to dot product of the camera viewing direction and the vertex normal. So the trick was not only to try transforming the camera normal but the vertex too:

Comment: In the end I used this:
`vertexNormal = gl_NormalMatrix*gl_Normal;`
`vertexViewDirection = -normalize(gl_ModelViewMatrix*gl_Vertex).xyz;`

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for (deprecated) [gluLookAt](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) are the components of (vec3) eye_, center_ and up_ (*x_ denotes vector-valued datum x_*)

```
f: ℝ^3 x ℝ^3 x ℝ^3 -> ℝ4xℝ4 
eye_, center_, up_ -> ViewMatrix
```

thus what you likely look for is

```
dir_ = normalize(center_ - eye_),
```

How and where you best get them in your shader depends on the GL and GLSL version you use.

This vector

> ```
> vec3(1.0, 1.0, -1,0);
> ```
>
> btw has length sqrt(3), thus it's not normalized.

EDIT

After knowing the OpenGL and GLSL versions one can take from

[**legacy GLSL 1.10.59  doc**](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.10.59.pdf)

that GLSL 1.10.59 already had custom uniforms (*I could not recall that for sure from memory, 2.0/1.10 are too long ago*); thus you simply pass that vector in as a uniform, and that's it.

Because it's used for every vertex, it's more anyway more efficient to calculate it once than doing it for every vertex again in the shader (given the rendered chunk of vertices is reasonbly large, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a way to compute this normal _in the vertex shader_. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Corbie Sure, but please post your GL and GLSL version!

Comment: @Corbie and the uniforms you populate you shader with, if any.

Comment: I've added the versions. There are no relevant uniforms.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a uniform to your shader. See docs for [glUniform3f](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml).

In client code, do something like this:

```
auto cameraUp = camera.getUp();
glUniform3f(uniformLocationInShader, cameraUp.x, cameraUp.y, cameraUp.z)
```

In the vertex shader, add a uniform for the camera up vector and then use it as intended.

```
uniform vec3 cameraUp;

void main() 
{
   // do stuff with cameraUp
}
```

Comment: I know this would be clever, but this is exactly what I'm trying not to do ;-)

Comment: Well, you need to pass some sort of uniform to the shader in order to get this information... If you have the view matrix as a uniform, you should be able to get the up vector from one of those columns.

Comment: So I guess this is the only way to do this? Can't I use the eye planes or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what uniforms are intended to do: pass information to the shaders... Btw, the near and far clip planes are part of your *projection* matrix. This isn't related to your camera's up vector.

Comment: Well I just need the z-vector. Can I extract it from the projection matrix?

Comment: @Corbie: well, you can extract the viewing direction from the projection martrix. But only the _eye space_ viewing direction. And the whole point of eye space is that both camera location and orientation are fixed in that space, so you can now the result of that _beforehand_: it will be `-z` fot the typical GL projection matrix. See me answer for why what you are trying to do is not possible.